# image embedded in a Custom Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to use image in Custom Server Control ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` class in your server control and expose whatever properties of it you need through your control, then when you do your rendering, call the Image's rendering. That should let you compose a control using that class without too much extra effort.

Comment: A tip: have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx in order to avoid surprises when starting to add controls dynamically

Comment: when I create images directory and assign imageurl to it , the image doesn't appear !

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you sure that the URL to the image is correct in reference to where you are placing the control?